# MS SQl show empty results

Tags: sql-server

Below query is matching if the partner code below is having asset code, but if no match its not showing it.

i need even if the partner_code is not having asset code to show any result null or 0

```
select Asset_code, partner_code from Asset
where PARTNER_CODE in  ('28800330',
'28800332',
'28800014',
'41900139',
'28800210',
'29200298',
'29200149',
'29200259',
'29200086',
'29400280',
'29000314',
'29000224',
'29600306',
'29100045',
'29800530',
'29800543',
'29900474',
'29700298',
'27400112',
'27400648',
'27400668',
'85400058',
'27300472',
'53200002',
'27800221',
'27800039',
'27200013')
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, do you want all the entries where the partner code is one from your list as well as any entries where the partner code is null?

Comment: Do you have `Partner` table?

Comment: yes i have partner table,

Comment: i have also partner code 28800330 is not having asset code but i want to show that its blank result

Comment: `select .. from partner LET JOIN asset ...`